# mulitiple files to extract a similar word table from each to excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have in excess of 300 word documents that include word tables, and I have been trying to write a VBA script for excel to extract the information I need, and I am completely new to Visual Basic. I need to copy the file name to the first cell, and the following cells to contain the information I am trying to extract, followed by the next file name, looping on until all word documents have been searched and extracted. I have tried multiple different ways, but the closest code I can find is as follows. It works to pull part numbers, but not descriptions. It also pulls extraneous information that doesn't need to be there, but I can work around that information if it is a necessary hazard.
I have an example word file (replaced sensitive information with other information), but I am not sure how to attach the word document or jpegs of page 1 and 2 of the word document. I know it would be beneficial if you could see it, so please let me know how to get it on here or to you so you can see it.

So to re-iterate:

- I need the file name in the first cell (A1)
- I need a certain cell out of table 3 from a word document to excel
- If at all possible, I need descriptions in column B (B2:B?) and
  mixture of letters and numbers in column C (C2:C?), then on the next
  line down, the next file name (A?), and continue to repeat. If you
  have any ideas, or suggestions, please let me know. And if I can't
  post the picture, or the actual sample document, I am willing to
  email, or any other means necessary to get help on this.

Here is the code I have been trying to manipulate. I found it and it was for a first and last row of a form, and I tried to get it to work, for my purposes to no avail:

```
Sub GetTablesFromWord()

   'this Excel file must be in
   'the same folder with the Word
   'document files that are to be'processed.    
   Dim wApp As Word.Application  
   Dim wDoc As Word.Document  
   Dim wTable As Word.Table  
   Dim wCell As Word.Cell 
   Dim basicPath As String  
   Dim fName As String     

   Dim myWS As Worksheet  
   Dim xlCell As Range  
   Dim lastRow As Long  
   Dim rCount As Long  
   Dim cCount As Long  
   Dim RLC As Long  
   Dim CLC As Long    
   basicPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator  
   'change the sheet name as required  
   Set myWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  
   'clear any/all previous data on the sheet  myWS.Cells.Clear     

   '"open" Word  Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")  
   'get first .doc file name in the folder  
   'with this Excel file  
   fName = Dir(basicPath & "*.doc*")
    Do While fName <> ""
       'this puts the filename into column A to
       'help separate the table data in Excel
       myWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
       "FILE: [" & fName & "]"
       'open the Word file
       wApp.Documents.Open basicPath & fName
       Set wDoc = wApp.Documents(1)
       'if there is a table in the
       'Word Document, work with it
       If wDoc.Tables.Count > 0 Then
         Set wTable = wDoc.Tables(3)
         rCount = wTable.Rows.Count
         cCount = wTable.Columns.Count
           For RLC = 1 To rCount
           lastRow = myWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
           For CLC = 1 To cCount
          'if there are merged cells in the
          'Word table, an error will be
          'generated - ignore the error,
          'but also won't process the data
          On Error Resume Next
          Set wCell = wTable.Cell(RLC, CLC)
          If Err <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            Else
            If CLC = 1 Then 
             Set xlCell = myWS.Range("A" & lastRow)
              xlCell = wCell
            Else
              Set xlCell = myWS.Range("B" & lastRow)
              xlCell = wCell
            End If
          End If
          On Error GoTo 0
        Next
      Next
      Set wCell = Nothing
      Set wTable = Nothing
    End If ' end of wDoc.Tables.Count test
    wDoc.Close False
    Set wDoc = Nothing
    fName = Dir()
 ' gets next .doc* filename in the folder
  Loop  wApp.Quit
  Set wApp = Nothing
  MsgBox "Task Completed"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code loops through all of the .docx files contained within a folder, extracts data into your spreadsheet, closes the word document, and moves onto the next document. The name of the word document gets extracted into Column A, and a value from within the 3rd table in the document is extracted into Column B. This should be a good starting point for you to build upon.

```
   Sub wordScrape()

Dim wrdDoc As Object, objFiles As Object, fso As Object, wordApp As Object
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim x As Integer

FolderName = "C:\code" ' Change this to the folder containing your word documents

Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.application")
Set objFiles = fso.GetFolder(FolderName).Files

x = 1
For Each wd In objFiles
    If InStr(wd, ".docx") And InStr(wd, "~") = 0 Then
        Set wrdDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(wd.Path, ReadOnly = True)
        sh1.Cells(x, 1) = wd.Name
        sh1.Cells(x, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(wrdDoc.Tables(3).Cell(Row:=3, Column:=2).Range)
        'sh1.Cells(x, 3) = ....more extracted data....
        x = x + 1
    wrdDoc.Close
    End If

Next wd
wordApp.Quit
End Sub
```